# Titanium mobile get variable from event listener in loop

Tags: iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

Hope this makes sense, I am using Titanium mobile to build an iPhone app. I have an array of 100 items each item has an DishID and an DishTitle, I show the DishTitle in a tableview and on the event listener I need to pass the DishID and use alert it for now on the event listener I will later do something with the items ID this is my code so far:

```
var dishes = eval(this.responseText);

for (var i = 0; i < dishes.length; i++)
            {

                DishID[i] = dishes[i].DishID;

                var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow();
                    row.selectedBackgroundColor = '#fff';
                    row.height = 30;
                    row.className = 'datarow';
                    row.clickName = 'row';

                // Create the label to hold the screen name
                name[i] = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
                    color:'#000',
                    font:{fontSize:16,fontWeight:'bold', fontFamily:'Arial'},
                    left:5,
                    top:2,
                    height:30,
                    width:200,
                    text:dishes[i].DishTitle
                });

                name[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){

                                 alert(DishID[i]);
                            });

            }
```

The issue I am having I keep getting the same ID 208 no matter which Label I click, am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I would like to know how 'dishes' is being initialized. Have you verified that they are all different ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a scope / closure issue.  By the time the 'click' happens, i=208.  I find it best to put the eventListener on the table, and custom attribue on the row:

```
var table = Ti.UI.createTableView();
var rows = [];

for(var i = 0; i < dishes.length; i++) {

    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
        selectedBackgroundColor : '#fff',
        height : 30,
        className : 'datarow'
    });

    row.dishId = dishes[i].DishID;

    // Create the label to hold the screen name
    var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        color : '#000',
        font : {
            fontSize : 16,
            fontWeight : 'bold',
            fontFamily : 'Arial'
        },
        left : 5,
        top : 2,
        height : 30,
        width : 200,
        text : dishes[i].DishTitle
    });

    row.add(label)

    rows.push(row);
}

table.setData(rows);

table.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert(e.row.dishId);
});
```